# Problemas consumiendo api rest desde angular

Tags: angular, api, rest, angular5

Tengo una api rest con un cors filter

```
package com.constellation.market.config;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


// When @EnableWebSecurity is on then @Component shouldnt be used else the filter will be registered twice
@Component
public class BasicCorsFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version");

    // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
    if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    return;
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}


}
```

Cuando consumo el servicio desde mi app angular , el de login lo coge bien y me autentico

```
 userAuthentication(userName: string, password: string){
  var data = "grant_type=password&username="+userName+"&password="+password;

  let headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

  headers = headers.append('Content-Type',  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic b25lbW9yZWNsaWVudGlkOlhZN2ttem9OemwxMDA=');

  return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, data, {headers: headers}).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Pero cuando invoco el servicio `getMe` que me da el usuario autenticado este error

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/me/data: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Este es el código del servicio `getMe()`

```
getUserMe(){
   return this.http.get(this.getMe, {headers : new HttpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('userToken')})}).catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

POr favor ayuda , Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` en tu `userAuthentication()` prueba y me dices

Comment: Eso ya se lo seteo en el CorsFilter , y el servicio de login lo hace bien , el problema es el resto de los servicios que cuando hago llamadas a ellos con el token en la cabecera que obtuve de la autenticación , no hace la petición. Que puediera estar pasando????